# Sharepoint 2013 beginner struggling with workflows on Mac

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I've been working with Sharepoint 2013 for a week now and think I have some of the basics under control. However, I'm trying to build a simple workflow to automate our internal HR system to some degree.

The context:

We run Office365 and want to use Sharepoint for two things mainly - online storage for all our documents and workflows to automate repetitive tasks.
I use a Mac and not really interested in partitioning a part of it for running Windows or using virtualisation software - if necessary, we'd rather purchase a standard PC to do Sharepoint development on.
I do not have the experience or skills to code, but comfortable figuring out online tools.
Questions:

Can I build attached workflow, without code and, preferably, without Sharepoint designer that can do the following: 1)E-signatures, 2) email notifications, 3) Complete forms?
Can I run Sharepoint designer on a Mac?
We'd like to control access to an individual's submitted documents so each individual can only view their own docs. Is it best to create a separate Library for each employee or keep all docs in the same library but grant access based on a log-in to individual files?
I know it is quite specific but even answering the 1st 2 questions will point me in the right direction by way of elimination.

[image: WorkFlow image]

Answer (score 3):

Your best option is probably to virtualize Windows on your mac (with Parallells, Vmware or Bootcamp). SP Designer is only supported on Windows and it looks to me as you need SP Designer to create the workflow above since it is not one of the OOTB ones